# SQL query for multiple join and count statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to create a query where I can get all the data I need to display a social media post such as comment count, like count, share count, and the necessary user data. Below is a picture of the database structure I have simplified down.

[Database Structure][image: 1]

Additionally from the stuff above, I also want to be able to sort this data given back by a timestamp which is in posts, as well as have an option to only return posts for a given user_id.

I'm moving away from noSQL so a little different, but I'm almost there. Here is what I have so far. I'm able to combine the user table and post table as well as sort by timestamp for a specific user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
JOIN users 
ON posts.user_id = users.id 
WHERE posts.user_id = $1 
AND posts.created_at > $2 
ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Any help is great! Thank you!

Comment: so you did what you wanted to do correctly. not sure what is question ? are you having trouble writing the query that returns the counts?

Comment: @eshirvana yes, i need to somehow implement the counting of likes, comments etc.

Answer (score 0):

so if you need to count of likes would look like this.
This query returns number of likes per each post of user_id = $1
And the same method for number of shares and comments

```
SELECT 
Post_id , count(*) LikeCounts
FROM posts 
JOIN users 
   ON posts.user_id = users.id 
JOIN Likes
   ON Likes.Post_id = Posts.post_id
WHERE posts.user_id = $1 
GROUP BY
   Posts.Post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming vole_ids in comments and shares link the same way as likes (i.e. to post_id in posts)

Link the tables you want, group the data by user, and date

Add the counts you want.

eg:

```
SELECT 
    posts.user_id,
    posts.created_at,
    COUNT(users.id) AS user_count,
    COUNT(likes.vole_id) AS likes_count,
    COUNT(shares.vole_id) AS shares_count,
    COUNT(comments.vole_id) AS comment_count
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.post_id = likes.vole_id
LEFT JOIN shares ON posts.post_id = shares.vole_id
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.vole_id
WHERE posts.user_id = $1 
AND posts.created_at > $2 
GROUP BY posts.user_id, posts.created_at
ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 20
```